# Set multiple xlabels in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating 5 plots with some data. All of them should have the same ylabel but different xlabels given in the x_axis list. For example, the first scatter plot should have the xlabel "A" and so on.

How can I manage this? thank you

```
def test(x):
 x_axis = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

 #DATA
 x = df[x_axis[x]]
 y = df["Return +1M"]
 y2 = df["Return +3M"]
 y3 = df["Return +6M"]

 colors = ['b', 'r', 'g']

 #SCATTER PLOT 
 return_1m = plt.scatter(x,y, marker="x", color=colors[0])
 return_3m = plt.scatter(x,y2, marker="x", color=colors[1])
 return_6m = plt.scatter(x,y3, marker="x", color=colors[2])

 plt.legend((return_1m, return_3m, return_6m),
           ('Return +1M', 'Return +3M', 'Return +6M'),
           scatterpoints=1,
           loc='lower right',
           ncol=1,
           fontsize=8)

 plt.ylabel("Return")
 plt.show()

for i in [0,1,2,3,4]:
 test(i)
```

Comment: Create [multiple subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html), possibly with `sharey=True`. Loop through the `axes` list and set each x-axis label with the corresponding value with `ax.set_xlabel()`. Then spend some time [with the tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5) = plt.subplots(1,5)

# Whatever you want your values to be:-
ax1.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,10], 'go')
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,11], 'b*') 


#X labels:-

ax1.set_xlabel('whatever you want')  
ax2.set_xlabel('whatever you want')
ax3.set_xlabel('whatever you want')
ax4.set_xlabel('whatever you want')
ax5.set_xlabel('whatever you want')
#You can do same with Y axis
```

You can also use loop to set xlabel. This way you won't require to write same line again and again